# I cannot go to next page with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I hope this message finds you all well. As a novice user of Selenium, I am seeking assistance with a task related to my university project. Specifically, I am attempting to download images from the website 'realself'. Currently, I am utilizing the code below to save all images on the initial page successfully. However, upon clicking on the subsequent pages to retrieve additional images, the page index changes in the browser, but the images remain the same as those on the first page. Any suggestions or guidance to overcome this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import urllib.request
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time


options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'D:\\program\\driver\\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.realself.com/photos/dermal-fillers#page=1&tags=&location=2038")
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(5)

# loop over pages
for page_num in range(1, 283):
    print(f'start saving images in page : {page_num}')

    # find all images in each page
    before_images = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='fixed-img2'][1]")
    after_images = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='fixed-img2'][2]")
    time.sleep(10)

    # loop over before images
    for index, before_image in enumerate(before_images):
        try:
            image_source = before_image.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='lazyloaded').get_attribute('src')
            print(f'before image: {image_source}')
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_source, f"dermal-fillers/before/image{index}.jpg")
        except:
            print(f'this image have some problem {before_image}')

    # loop over after images
    for index, after_image in enumerate(after_images):
        try:
            image_source = after_image.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'lazyloaded').get_attribute('src')
            print(f'after image: {image_source}')
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(image_source, f"dermal-fillers/after/image{index}.jpg")
        except:
            print(f'this image have some problem {after_image}')

    # go to the next page
    driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 30).
                          until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "Pager-forward"))))
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "Pager-forward").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    print('go to next page')


driver.quit()
print('end')
```

Comment: Rather than trying to "click through" why not change the *page* value in the URL and do another *get()* ? As an aside... you may want to consider multithreading this otherwise it's going to take rather a long time (especially with all the seemingly unnecessary *sleep()* calls)

Comment: Unfortunately, even after attempting to access the URLs of different pages using the get() method, the resulting images remained the same.

Comment: I guess pages won't load correctly once you are identified as a bot. Try introducing some sleep time inside the loops where you get images. Also checkout [undetected-chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/). Use a VPN or restart your router once you've been flagged as bot.

Comment: Also images from page 2 will overwrite images from page 1 in your current code. increment `index` from page to page or add `page_num` to your file name

Comment: Thank you kindly for your response. I greatly appreciate your suggestion regarding the inclusion of page numbers when saving images. In regard to VPN usage, I have employed Nekoray for this purpose, but unfortunately, it has only been effective for two pages. Following your recommendation to use "undetected-chromedriver," I have implemented it, but to no avail, as the website still identifies me as a bot.